# How to change punctuation (In) to (In:) for citing a book chapter in an edited book

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing, citing

I am using the MWE from [enter link description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173638/move-names-of-editors-followed-by-ed-eds-and-a-comma-before-title-in-biblate) where I need to cite a book chapter in an edited book.

How can we change some of the `punctuation`?

I need to change from:

```
In
```

to

```
In:
```

Basically:

[image]

to:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the linked question and answer contains the line

```
\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\space}
```

As you can see in the following reduced MWE

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\space}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,pines}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

this causes the "in" to be followed only by a space and not by a colon.

[image: No colon after "in"]

Simply remove that line and you will get back the preset value of `\addcolon\space`, which gives you a colon.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\space}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,pines}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: "In:" with colon]

Comment: thanks. Brillant! Any idea about `Author A and Author B (2017). Title` to `Author A and Author B (2017) Title`. To delete the `.` punctuation after the year. Should I ask a new question?

Comment: @aan `\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addspace}` or if that doesn't work because you are using an outdated system `\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace}`.

Comment: @aan Generally I would urge you to ask a new question, but this would be pretty much a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28892/35864, so you don't need to bother in this case. Of course you should ask a new question if my suggestions don't work.